# Yolov8 transfer learning

Tags: python, yolo

I'm sure this is a misunderstanding on my part, but is there a way to add new classes to the pretrained models and it keep the original classes?

Whenever I add a new class using the python training example in the ultralytics docs the new classes show up OK in the images, but all the other classes are gone.

If I understand this correctly, it appears that I need to add the new classes I wish to detect to the whole COCO (or whatever other massive data set) and retrain from scratch. Either that or run the new model and the original and make two detection queries to detect the original classes and my new ones. This doesn't feel like it scales very well if I create a new model for each new class(s).

I'm asking because this feels wrong, but I can't find anything that suggests otherwise.

I created a new custom class, with the yaml config, used the simple python script in the example docs (https://docs.ultralytics.com/tasks/classify/#models).

Using COCO128 I trained the model on just the new class and all the original classes disappeared. I then added my new classes to the config (class 80) and it worked with the new classes as well as very poorly with the original ones (it was COCO128 after all). This lead me to conclude that I would need to retrain on the whole coco set and my new class to get a reasonable model that keeps the original output and my one new class.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like my assumption was correct and you won't keep the weights from the original training unless you retrain from scratch with your new classes added.

It looks like the options are:

1. retrain and add new classes to get one model with everything in
2. create a new model that is specifically for the new classes and the original for the generic detections.

From:
https://community.ultralytics.com/t/how-to-combine-weights-to-detect-from-multiple-*datasets/38/2
KalenMichael
Feb '22
To add to what @Glenn has posted, an existing weight file cannot have new classes added to it. A new weight file will need to be trained with all the required classes and datasets.
@khandriod The options in your specific case are
Combine your two datasets and train a new model.
Train a new model with multiple datasets as explained by @Glenn
Whatever route you decide to go, you will need to train a new model if you want it to detect all of the classes.*

Answer (score 0):

The challenge you're encountering is known as [**catastrophic forgetting**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_interference#:%7E:text=Catastrophic%20forgetting%20occurs%20because%20when,top%20of%20the%20old%20ones.). This refers to a phenomenon in which a neural network loses its previously acquired knowledge once trained on a new task. This can occur because the network essentially readjusts its weights for the new task, potentially overwriting the important weights associated with the prior task.

It's worth noting that YOLOv8 doesn't inherently provide a built-in solution to mitigate catastrophic forgetting, given its relatively recent introduction.

A technique that might help with this issue is **rehearsal** or **fine-tuning with replay**. This technique involves incorporating data from original classes that you want to retain into the training process along with new classes. Adjust the balance between old and new data based on your needs for optimal results.

You can find more details about this problem here [Is there any solution for Catastrophic Inference with YOLOv8 yet?](https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/issues/4282)